# Exporting Json data in asp.net vb from MS SQL

Tags: asp.net, json, sql-server

I am trying to export data from MS SQL out in a json format in my asp.net web forms application.   Problem is it exports with two double quotes around the values instead of just one double quote.
I want it to export like this:

```
{"bizunitid":"11111","prodlineid":"1","reasonforsurvey":"1"}
```

but it is coming out like this:

```
"{""bizunitid"":""11111"",""prodlineid"":""1"",""reasonforsurvey"":""2""}"
```

I have tried replacing the two double quotes but it always returns two double quotes.

```
 Dim json As String = cmd.ExecuteScalar
 streamWriter.Write(json.Replace("""""", Chr(34)))
```

Comment: How are you getting it out?

Comment: sqlConn.Open()
                    Dim PostData As String = cmd.ExecuteScalar
                    sqlConn.Close()

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but it's how I've done it when posting JSon to an API for a messaging app with VB.Net:

```
MessageTitle = MessageTitle.Replace("""", """""")
MessageBody = MessageBody.Replace("""", """""")

Dim strPostData As String = "{" &
"""notification"": {" &
"""sound"": ""default""," &
"""title"": """ & MessageTitle & """," &
"""body"": """ & MessageBody & """" &
"}, " &
"""data"": {" &
"""title"": """ & MessageTitle & """," &
"""body"": """ & MessageBody & """" &
"}," &
"""to"": """ & strRegIDs & """," &
"""priority"": 10 " &
"}"
```

hopefully that helps a bit